# Error plot2D GUI MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, plot, matlab-figure

I have this code:

```
h=plot(elapsedTime(1:length(elapsedTime)),velocityMagnitudeCentroide,'Parent',handles.grafico s2D)h=plot(elapsedTime(1:length(elapsedTime)),velocityMagnitudeCentroide,'Parent',handles.graficos2D);

hhTitle=title(gca,'Head Filtered 3D Velocity');
hhXLabel=xlabel(gca,'time(s)');
hhYLabel=ylabel(gca,'Velocity (m/s)');
hLegend = legend(h,'Head');

z=plot3(x3D,y3D,z3D,'Parent',handles.graficos3D);
set(handles.ui_label1, 'String', 'Max');
set(handles.ui_label2, 'String', 'Mean');
set(handles.ui_label3, 'String', 'Min');

hTitle=title('3D Position');
hXLabel=xlabel('time(s)');
hYLabel=ylabel('3D Position(m)');
```

which outputs this:[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: THE PROBLEM: in the 2D Plot, the title and the name of the axis doesnt show up!

Comment: already figured out the answer...

Comment: answer: hhTitle=title(handles.graficos2D,'Head Filtered 3D Velocity');

Comment: Please either answer your own question by placing an answer below your post, or delete the post all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

already figured it out..

answer: `hhTitle=title(handles.graficos2D,'Head Filtered 3D Velocity');`

Matlab is sensitive when he has two or more plots.. so you need to "actually" name the plot you wanna plot something.